# Keras with TensorFlow --- Adding regularizer on layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

The code needed more challenges for the architecture and also I am also working on my own architecture so I ask this as the semantics are changing every day: Are the present symantics OK?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(w_l2),
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3),  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(w_l2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(w_l2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note that on Stack OVerflow you should include error messages and code *in the question, itself* and not as images. Images are often difficult to read and the content cannot be copied for seaching or testing.

Answer (score 1):

The first error comes from the fact that you have now imported the necessary libraries.

As per the documentation of TensorFlow 2.0, the correct way to add an L2 regularizer is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l=0.01)
```

If you use plain `keras`(I strongly recommend that you **switch** to `keras` inside `tensorflow`), you would just need to omit the 'tf'.

Practically, it would be `keras.regularizers.l2` instead of `tf.keras.regularizers.l2`.

The second image that you uploaded does not throw an error; in fact, it shows a warning that you are using a deprecated function and that you should use the suggested code in the warning rather than how you defined your code.